# Coding a Recursive Functions

Tags: php

I have coded this function to accept either an array of numbers or a variable with a single number assigned to it. Now when I pass a variable with a single  number it works fine but when an array is passed it is returning me an error (Array to string conversion).

Please see my example below can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
function recusive($data){
    if(is_array($data)){
        $price = array();
        foreach($data as $number){
            $price[] = recruisive($number);
        }
    }else{
        $formatted = number_format($data,2);
        $price = '£' . $formatted;
    }

    return $price;
}

$input = array(130, 333, 444, 555);

echo recursive($input);
```

Comment: `$price[] = recruisive($number);` Different function, or misspelling?

Comment: You misspelled the name of function. In line 2 it says `recusive` and in line 6 it is `recruisive`. And finally it the 16 line you call function using `recursive`...

Comment: `recusive`, `recruisive`, `recursive` - you have way too many typos.

Comment: Well, for one, you have a typo/misspelling here `$price[] = recruisive($number);` If that typo doesn't exist in your actual code, please post your actual code and not a reproduction of it.

Comment: **always provide input, expected output, complete error message and the offending line**

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning an array.  Try:

```
print_r(recursive($input));
```

Or loop through it and display:

```
foreach(recursive($input) as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Also, you have attempted `recursive` 3 times and have only spelled it correctly 1 time: recusive, recruisive, recursive